# Show zeroes if right two digits are zero

Tags: sql, sapb1

I am having trouble solving this one. If i have the following values stored in U_pmHours

3.00
4.25
5.50

The following code correctly gives me the two digits after the decimal place

```
RIGHT(FORMAT(CONVERT(DECIMAL(4,2),T2.U_pmHours)/2,'N2'),2) AS 'TEST 2'
```

So the new values will be

00
25
50

The problem i am having is converting these values to minutes using * 60 /100, it works as it should on everything that isnt 00, instead of still showing 00 it shows as blank.

What can i do to make it either not do the calculation if the digits after the decimal are 00 (3.00) or to still show 00 in this case.

Comment: Where do you do the multiplication and division? show the full expression. Multiplication forces an implicit conversion from string (the result of `RIGTH...` to number, and you need to format that again with N2

Comment: Hi tinazmu, RIGHT(FORMAT(CONVERT(DECIMAL(4,2),T2.U_pmHours)/2,'N2'),2) * 60 / 100

Comment: This would convert the string '00' to a number (to perform the multiplication), 00 may not be considered a number. I don't know SAPB1, and its documentation doesn't seem to be publicly available. I suggest that you use integer truncation and subtraction to get the decimal fractions in number datatype, then multiply and then format to two digits. In some imaginary pseudo language it could be `format((U_PmHours-INT(U_pmHours))*60,'00')`, where INT is the 'integer part', and '00' could mean format this number as two digits with a leading zero

Comment: Is it SAP Business One on MS SQL Server, or on HANA?

Comment: Hi Sandra, it is SAP B1 MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved. My problem was that I was trying to use two different field types in the same column. On one end i was performing a calculation for one instance and then providing a string for the other.

I resolved this by simply converting the calculated part of the code to also be a varchar type.

```
CASE WHEN 
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(T2.U_pmHours AS DECIMAL(4,2)) / 2),3,2) = '00'
THEN '00'
ELSE
CAST(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(T2.U_pmHours AS DECIMAL(4,2)) / 2),3,2) * 60 / 100 AS VARCHAR)
```